# 'Cannot get role and feature data' - Roles no longer showing

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have a server running Windows Server 2012 with AD DS, DNS, WSUS, and a couple of other roles configured on it.

I logged into the server and the server manager does not show the device roles that it used to show in the dashboard. There is an error in the ‘Manageability’ section that says the server names and IPs and ‘Online – Cannot get role and feature data’.

What may be causing this?

I do not believe that anything has been done to the physical server in a while. I mostly just use it for testing VMs in Hyper-V. In December, I had a problem with one of the VMs where it would not fully shut down when I attempted to via the Hyper-V GUI. I ended up downloading Process Explorer and using it to shutdown the VM that was causing problems. This is the only problem that I have had with the physical server over the past several months.

EDIT:
I pulled up notifications and have one that says the task 'Automatic Refresh' failed. "Role and feature refresh failed with the following error: The request to list features available on the specified server failed. A DISM session could not be opened. An error occurred accessing the temporary folder C:\Windows\Temp\XXX-RANDOM-CHARACTERS-XXX

It looks like a similar error occured here:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/Windows_Server_2012/Q_28024759.html

That error occured after a couple of Windows Updates failed. I pulled up Windows Update and it appears that I had a bunch of updates fail on 12/16.

Comment: The Server Manager is notorious for not updating if there is a restart pending ...are you behind on updates?

Comment: @NathanC Thanks, I did not know that. See edit. The server updated on 12/16, but about half the updates failed. C: has been very nearly full for a couple of months now and I assume that's why the updates failed. If I add space and re-run the updates, I'm guessing I will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred as a result of updates failing because the HDD was full. I freed up space on the HDD and then Windows Update and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

CMorris, did reinstalling the updates help the issue or have any effect? I have the same issue on a production server.

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: @BlobIT - Yes, reinstalling updates resolved the issue.

Comment: Drew, you're right. I don't have enough "reputation" yet to comment directly. CMorris, thanks for replying. I'm working through a similar issue.